# How can I get a regular expression to only match an empty string? (In a .htaccess file)

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache, mod-rewrite, regular-expression

I try to make a regular expression in a .htaccess file, that matches only an empty string.

I have tried many things, but it seems like it’s impossible. For example, I tried `^$`, but it's looking for `""` that will always exist in a string.

So I seek answers to it all possible.

If possible, I would like to hear how to extend such a regular expression together.

Here is the content of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ https://stald-mariendal.dk/index_tekst [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^guestbook.html$ https://stald-mariendal.dk/gaestebog [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^sites/guestbook.html$ https://stald-mariendal.dk/gaestebog [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^guestbook$ https://stald-mariendal.dk/gaestebog [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^(\w+).html$ https://stald-mariendal.dk/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^sites/(\w+).html$ https://stald-mariendal.dk/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ?site=$1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}| off
RewriteRule (.*) https://stald-mariendal.dk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: "I tried `^$`, but it's looking for `""` that will always exist in a string." - What behaviour are you seeing that appears to suggest this? `^` and `$` are anchors indicating the start and end of the string respectively, so what you are suggesting is _impossible_.

Answer (score 5):

I wasn't convinced this would work, but I've tested it and it does seem to.

Quite simply:

```
^.{0}$
```

Where:

`^` is the start of the match

`.` is any character (except newline)

`{0}` is precisely zero times

`$` is the end of the match

Comment: "simply" - There is no need for this additional _complexity_. `^.{0}$` is the same as _simply_ `^$`. The fact that the OP appears to suggest that `^$` does not to work implies there is _something else_ amiss.

Comment: Aha. I had (mis)understood that `^$` meant the same as `^[.\n]*$` - ie. *match absolutely any character (including newline), any number of times*. I'll take it from your comment above that it actually means *match absolutely zero characters*. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Yes, `^` and `$` are anchors for the start and end of the _string_. So when placed together there cannot be anything in between. In fact, this can be further simplified to just `^` or `$` (the former is more common) for a zero-length match.

Comment: I hear that there clearly are divided on what ^ and $ do and what it means when they are together.

Comment: So I am looking for expert knowledge on what ^ and $ means and what it means when you put ^ at the beginning of the regular expression and $ at the end of the regular expression.

Comment: I've tried the `^$`, this doesn't work  in all environments, the `^.{0}$` does (too bad I cant remember where environment didnt work)

Comment: I've tried this ^$ and It works, I use this expresion for a Wechall excercise, and the answer was /^$/